# Why I can't get the doc that added recently by IndexWriter in the search result in Lucene 4.0?

Tags: lucene

Such as the title said, I have encountered a puzzled problem.
I have built an index for my test program, then I use IndexWriter to add a document into index. The code is :

```
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, analyzer);
IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
Document doc1 = new Document();
doc1.add(new Field("name", "张三", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc1.add(new IntField("year", 2013, Field.Store.YES));
doc1.add(new TextField("content", "123456789", Field.Store.YES));
iwriter.addDocument(doc1);
iwriter.commit();
iwriter.close();
```

When I try to search in this index, I can't get this doc. I really get a correct result count, it is one more than before. But when I try to print the doc.get('name'), the output is wrong.

The code in search part is:

```
DirectoryReader ireader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
System.out.println(ireader.numDeletedDocs());
IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(ireader);
// Parse a simple query that searches for "text":
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "name", analyzer);
Query query = parser.parse("张");

ScoreDoc[] hits = isearcher.search(query, null, 1000).scoreDocs;
System.out.println(hits.length);
```

In results, there is a "Name: 李四".
I'm sure that I use the StandardAnalyzer during indexing and searching. And StandardAnalyzer will make one Chinese character as a single token. Why when I search "张", I will get "李四"? Is there anything wrong when I add a doc? Or the docid is mismatch?

Comment: please try printing out the query and notice if it is as expected..

Comment: Can you provide the code used to retrieve the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you (re)open the index after adding the doc? Lucene searches only return the documents that existed as of the time the index was opened for searching.

*[edit...]*

Use **IndexReader.Open()** or **IndexReader.doOpenIfChanged()** to open the index again. **doOpenIfChanged()** has the advantage that it returns null if you can still use the old IndexReader instance (because the index has not changed).

*(If I recall correctly, **DirectoryReader.Open()** just opens the index directory, so the higher-level Lucene code does not realize that the index has changed if you just call **DirectoryReader.Open**.)*

Comment: Is re-opening the index anything different from `DirectoryReader.open(directory);` ???   The [example at apache site](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/overview-summary.html) only does a single `directory.close()` at the end.  Is there another close/open that is needed between adding the document and searching for it?